# How to export Required Plugins functionality in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

There is a function in ItelliJ which is Required Plugins.
I want to make plugin X required in our project, so our team will be prompted to install it.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Required plug-ins](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#required-plugins) are saved in the project inside `.idea/externalDependencies.xml` file which can be [shared via the version control](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839).

Comment: Looks amazing. I'm wondering if its possible to set it in a different path?

Comment: The path is not customizable.